# How to do simple login using IDs in swift

Tags: swift, xcode

I want to create login functions in Swift using simple validation, but this doesn't work .
What should I do? When I write ***123456*** in text field and then click on the login button, this should do go to next page:

```
   @IBOutlet weak var IDtext: UITextField!

        var ID = self.IDtext.text 

            @IBAction func LogButton(_ sender: Any) {

            If( ID == "123456" )
        {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), 
{ 
() -> Void in let viewController:UIViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Home") as! UIViewController
                        self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }

         }
        else 
        {
       var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Invalid", message: "Invalid ID", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
            alert.show()
         }
            }
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the variable initialisation inside the function's body and change your function to this:

```
@IBAction func LogButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

        if self.IDtext.text?.isEmpty == false{
            if (self.IDtext.text? == "123456"){
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Home") 
self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
           }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@IBAction func LogButton(_ sender: Any) {

```
  var ID = self.IDtext.text 
  if ID = "123456" {
    let pushVC:UIViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Home") as! UIViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(pushVC, animated: true)
  } else {
     var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Invalid", message: "Invalid ID", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
        alert.show()
  }
}
```

Also if the name of your home class is Something say "HomeVC" then replace your line as follows:-

```
let pushVC:UIViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Home") as! HomeVC
```

Answer (score 0):

In button click event first check you `textField` is empty or not, If yes then show error other wise get your next view controller from `Storyboard` using `Identifier` and next push your next `controller` on navigation stack.

```
    @IBAction func btnLogin(_ sender: UIButton) {

        if (self.IDtext.text?.isEmpty)! {

            // Show Error
        }

        else if (self.IDtext.text? == "12456"){

            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: storyboard, bundle: nil)
            let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "nextController") 
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBAction func LogButton(_ sender: Any) {

  var ID = self.IDtext.text 
  if ID = "123456" && ID != "" {
    let pushVC:UIViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Home") as! UIViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(pushVC, animated: true)
  } else {
    // else part
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use textfield delegate properties, and use 
                 func textField(UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn: NSRange, replacementString: String) to check the string in real time